# Googleplay purchases.products.acknowledge return 400 not a valid state and 409 cocurrentUpdate

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

We try to do acknowledge google play purchase on the server-side through [purchases.products.acknowledge](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/acknowledge) with golang

However, the following errors come up sometime

```
googleapi: Error 409: The operation could not be performed since the object was 
already in the process of being updated., concurrentUpdate
```

```
googleapi: Error 400: The purchase is not in a valid state to perform the desired operation
```

Is there anything am I missing? or how to solve those errors?

Answer (score 1):

Per google support

- For error 400, the purchaseState must be Purchased or 0 before you can acknowledge the purchase. For more information, please refer to this page: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process

  Error 400 can also mean that you already acknowledged the purchase.
- For error 409, this means you are acknowledging the purchase multiple times concurrently. Unfortunately, we don't provide support for API concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

Currently having this exactly issue, did you manage to resolve it in the end.

```
Acknowledgement Request Response:  {
  error: {
    code: 409,
    message: 'The operation could not be performed since the object was already in the process of being updated.',
    errors: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

I'm only sending it once, after i have validated and added to my database. I'm not sure why its happening.

EDIT:
I had a theory my code was executing to fast and maybe the order was still pending, so i added a 10 second gap between getting purchase token and then trying to acknowledge once again. Im now getting the following.

```
Acknowledgement Request Response:  {
  error: {
    code: 400,
    message: 'The purchase is not in a valid state to perform the desired operation.',
    errors: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

However at this time in Google Play Console, the state is Chargeable, meaning it just needs to be acknowledged.

Comment: First of all, please make sure only when both purchaseState and acknowledgeState of receipt are all 0, then to do acknowledge. Secondly, please make sure only the server does acknowledge rather than the client also does that. The acknowledge seems to work well on my server side.

Comment: `the state is Chargeable, meaning it just needs to be acknowledged.` you mentioned. I am not clear about this state. Could you please figure out where does the meaning of this field come from?

Comment: I figured it out in the end, i accidentally left my client side code running so it was acknowledging both client and server at the same time.